# Best optimal LINQ with changing old dctionary to the new one

Tags: c#, linq, optimization

I have some script, which first checks if in database are some values, and then depending on that values it creates new collection. I dont know if that result is the best I cant get i think no. If anybody can help me with this, I will be grateful

```
var tempDict = request.Number_Name
            .Where(k => _context.Users.Where(x => x.Status == 0).Select(x => x.Phone).Contains(k.Key) || _context.Users.Where(x => x.Status == 0).Select(x => x.PhoneWithoutCC).Contains(k.Key))
            .ToDictionary(k => k.Key, v => v.Value);

            var finalDict = new Dictionary<string, string>();
            foreach (var kv in tempDict)
            {
                var number = _context.Users.Where(x => x.Status == 0).Where(x => kv.Key == x.PhoneWithoutCC || kv.Key == x.Phone).Select(x => new { x.Phone, x.DisplayName }).FirstOrDefault();
                if (!kv.Key.Contains("+"))
                {

                    finalDict[number.Phone] = number.DisplayName;
                }
                else
                {
                    finalDict[kv.Key] = number.DisplayName;
                }
            }
```

Comment: if you are using lazy loading "_context.Users.Where(x => x.Status == 0)" will try to connect with the database everytime you will try to use it.

Comment: "finalDict[number.Phone] = number.DisplayName" can provoke null reference exception

Comment: This code would have horrific performance. You really need to hit the database a minimal number of times.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without the exact object model, and some good sample data, I can be sure if this is correct, but it does only hit the database once.

Let me know if this works:

```
var phones = request.Number_Name.Select(x => x.Key).ToArray();

var query =
    _context
        .Users
        .Where(x => phones.Contains(x.Phone) || phones.Contains(x.PhoneWithoutCC))
        .Where(x => x.Status == 0)
        .Select(x => new { x.Phone, x.PhoneWithoutCC, x.DisplayName })
        .ToArray();

var finalDict =
(
    from q in query
    from p in new [] { q.Phone, q.PhoneWithoutCC }
    join n in request.Number_Name on p equals n.Key
    let k = n.Key.Contains("+") ? q.Phone : n.Key
    group q.DisplayName by k
)
    .ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.First());
```

This also eliminates the need for the temporary dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

I am typing from a phone, so I have no way to check if it actually works :)
Just let me know and we will figure something out. 
First try to think from the context perspective to avoid loading data from db over and over again:

```
var result = (from n in  request.Number_Name
               join u in _context.Users 
                   on n.Key equals u.PhoneWithoutCC || n.Key equals u.Phone
               where u.Status == 0
               select new {
                            key = n.Key.Contains("+") ? n.Key : u.Phone,
                            DisplayName = u.DisplayName
                            })
               .ToDictionary(k = k.Key, v = v.DisplayName);
```